# Copying data using Data Copy into individual files for blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I am entirely new to Azure, so if this is easy please just tell me to RTFM, but I'm not used to the terminology yet so I'm struggling.

I've created a data factory and pipeline to copy data, using a simple query, from my source data. The target data is a .txt file in my blob storage container. This part is all working quite well.

Now, what I'm attempting to do is to store each row that's returned from my query into an individual file in blob storage. This is where I'm getting stuck, and I'm not sure where to look. This seems like something that'll be pretty easy, but as I said I'm new to Azure and so far am not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type 1 in the Max rows per file of the Sink setting and don't set the file name in the dataset of sink. If you need, you can specify the file name prefix in the File name prefix setting.

Screenshots:

The dataset of sink

[image]

Sink setting in the copy data activity

[image]

Result:

[image]